# How to get mixed results from Realm and display in list/recycler view

Tags: realm

Let's say I have two models A, and B. I need to get results with both A, and B in it. The list view could be something like

A 1
A 2
A 3
 
B 1
B 2
A 4
A 5
B 3

I realize it's not possible to get mixed results in Realm. It also appears we can't inherit a Realm https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761.

Here is one way through composition
[Best practice and how to implement RealmList that need to support different types of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884573/best-practice-and-how-to-implement-realmlist-that-need-to-support-different-type).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[The best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884573/best-practice-and-how-to-implement-realmlist-that-need-to-support-different-type) you've linked is the current best approach to achieve what you seek for.